# Android Java How i can add dynamically textViews on view with info from different hashmaps

Tags: java, android

I have several spinners and when selecting an item from each I need information to be displayed below.
When you click on the spinner element, the hashmap <String, String> is filled and you need to output Key: Value, all hashmaps are different, one can have three key-value pairs, another seven, etc.
for example:
Ability: SuperStrengh (and I need Key to be of one color and value of another)
attached picture for [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NsWmF.png)

Answer (score 1):

I guess my first question is: why have several Hashmaps when you can just have one? Also, does each key always get paired with the same value? If so, you probably want parallel lists instead.

LiveData plus using a ViewModel sounds like something that would help you out a lot here. LivaData will let you add listeners for when you change your variables, and a ViewModel will help you preserve data easily when the screen rotates, for example. Here are some guides on both of those:
https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/viewmodels-a-simple-example-ed5ac416317e
https://www.raywenderlich.com/10391019-livedata-tutorial-for-android-deep-dive

Here is an example of how you could get input from some spinners and update a text field based on the result. I also included how you could get all the key-value pairs from a HashMap if you really want.

```
package com.github.ajsnarr98.testingplayground;

import androidx.annotation.ArrayRes;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Spinner;

import com.github.ajsnarr98.testingplayground.databinding.ActivityMainBinding;

import java.util.HashMap;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {

    private ActivityMainBinding binding;

    private HashMap<String, String> someMap;

    /**
     * Simplifies setting up each spinner for example.
     */
    private void initSpinner(Spinner spinner, @ArrayRes int intResource) {
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
                this, intResource, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item
        );
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
        setContentView(binding.getRoot());

        // set up each spinner with items
        initSpinner(binding.spinner1, R.array.abilities_array);
        initSpinner(binding.spinner2, R.array.some_other_array);
        initSpinner(binding.spinner3, R.array.another_array);
        initSpinner(binding.spinner4, R.array.foo_array);

        someMap = new HashMap<>();
        someMap.put("ability", "super-strength");
        someMap.put("foo", "bar");

        // add a listener for each spinner item
        binding.spinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
        binding.spinner2.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
        binding.spinner3.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
        binding.spinner4.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        // An item was selected. You can retrieve the selected item using
        // parent.getItemAtPosition(pos)
        if (view == binding.spinner1) {
            // you can update your text view here, along with all your hashmaps
            binding.info1.setText("here is some text");
        } else if (view == binding.spinner2) {
            binding.info2.setText(onSpinner2Clicked(position));
        } else if (view == binding.spinner3) {
            binding.info3.setText(getStringForMap(someMap));
        } else if (view == binding.spinner4) {
            binding.info4.setText("here is some text");
        } else {
            throw new IllegalStateException("unhandled view selection");
        }
    }

    private String onSpinner2Clicked(int position) {
        return String.format("Here is some fancy text. I chose %s!",
                getResources().getStringArray(R.array.some_other_array)[position]);
    }

    private String getStringForMap(HashMap<String, String> map) {
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
        for (String key : map.keySet()) {
            result.append(String.format("%s : %s\n", key, map.get(key)));
        }
        return result.toString();
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
        // called when nothing becomes selected
    }
}
```

Comment: I guess my first question is: why have several Hashmaps when you can just have one?
A: cuz information from another spinner can have the same Key as in another.